# Bipartite dimension of an almost crown graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

A crown graph is a complete bipartite graph from which a perfect matching has been removed.

The bipartite dimension of a graph is the minimum number of complete bipartite subgraphs needed to cover all the edges of the graph.

The bipartite dimension of a crown graph with $2n$ vertices is

$\sigma(n)=\min\left\{k \hspace{0.2cm} |\hspace{0.2cm} n\leq\begin{pmatrix}k\\\lfloor k/2\rfloor\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

This formula is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_graph#Properties).

> My question is: how can we derive such a formula?

My actual problem is to compute the bipartite dimension of the following graph **where the blue edges are removed** from the crown graph.
It means **two** perfect matchings have been removed from a complete bipartite graph.

[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What's a crown graph? What's "bipartite dimension"? (Wikipedia is anunrelaible guide to standard notation.)

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I made some edits.

Comment: In general, which two matchings have been removed? A cycle? The covers constructed for a complete graph minus a cycle also work. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227918/covering-the-zeros-of-0-1-matrix-with-submatrices

Comment: @DouglasZare Yes, I suppose that in order to obtain the matrix described in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227918/covering-the-zeros-of-0-1-matrix-with-submatrices, we have to remove two perfect matchings in cycle. I am trying to see if we can adapt the quantity $\sigma(n)$ to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(n,n)$ be a crown graph with $2n$ vertices. It has two parts $X$ and $\tilde{X}$, $|X|=\tilde{X}=n$, for each $x\in X$ there exists unique $\tilde{x}\in \tilde{X}$ such that $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ are not joined.

Let $C(n,n)$ be covered by complete bipartite subgraphs $G_1,\dots G_k$. For each vertex $x\in X$ denote by $M(x)$ the set of $i$ such that $x\in G_i$. Note that edge $(x,\tilde{y})$may belong to $G_i$ if and only if $x\in G_i$, $y\notin G_i$, i.e., $i\in M(x)\setminus M(y)$. Hence the problem reduces to Sperner's lemma on the existence of $n$ subsets of $k$-set such that none of them is contained in another. It is well-known that they exist if and only if $n\leqslant \binom{k}{[k/2]}$.

Comment: What I don't get in your argument is why if we have $M(x) \subset M(y)$ then we have the edge between $x$ and copy of $y$ not covered? And what do you mean by "copy of $y$"? Thanks!

Comment: Each vertex $x$ in the first part has its copy $\tilde{x}$ in the second part, which is the only vertex in the second part not joined with $x$. If $(x,\tilde{y})$ is an edge of $G_i$, then vertices $x, \tilde{y}$ belong to $G_i$, hence $y$ does not, i.e., $i\in M(x)\setminus M(y)$.

Comment: If there exist no edge between $x$ and $\tilde{y}$, we should not cover it. Hence instead Sperner's condition $M(x)\setminus M(y)\ne \emptyset$ for all $x\ne y$ we get it not for all pairs. On the other hand, we can not in general $M(x)$ with all $\tilde{y}$, $y\notin M(x)$. Well, this is just another question.